# How to execute cron distributed task in hazelcast IScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, hazelcast, distributed, spring-scheduled

I have hazelcast cluster and I'm currently using in my project TaskScheduler from Spring to execute cron tasks.

I would like to use hazelcast IScheduledExecutorService to schedule a cron task on all members, and to schedule a multiple cron tasks which will be distributed equally across cluster, but I can't find the appropriate method.

I can't find method in IScheduledExecutorService that have cron trigger in parameter, only timeUnit. Do you know any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

IScheduledExecutorService is not a full cron scheduler, for it only allows the scheduling of a single future execution and/or a fixed rate execution but not periodic executions at fixed times, dates or intervals. So if you are happy to do something like:

```
executorService.schedule(new SomeTask(), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

where SomeTask will run after 10 seconds, then you can choose any of the following APIs to submit your task:

scheduleOnMember: On a specific cluster member.
scheduleOnKeyOwner: On the partition owning that key.
scheduleOnAllMembers: On all cluster members.
scheduleOnAllMembers: On all given members.

Check reference manual for details: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/index.html#scheduled-executor-service

Comment: thank you for answer, do you know any alternative to IScheduledExecutorService that accept cron and allows distrubuted task scheduling across hazelcast members?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this quite easily, provided the edge cases will not be disastrous to you.
Instead of scheduling a task directly, you can create a wrapper that will be parameterized by a cron expression and your actual task. This wrapper will then interrogate the cron expression (there are libraries that do that) and get the next point in time to when this task should be scheduled and schedule itself accordingly using standard executorService.schedule method. When the wrapper is executed by the scheduler, it executes the internal task, interrogates itself for the next execution point and schedules itself accordingly.

Something like that

```
class CronTask implements Runnable {
  IScheduledExecutorService executor;
  CronExpression cronExpression;
  Runnable task;

  void run() {
    try {
      task.run();
    } finally {
      executor.schedule(this, getNextExecutionDelay();
    }

  }

  long getNextExecutionDelay() {
    //use cronExpression to calculate next delay
  }
}

//somewhere in the code
var cronTask = new CronTask(executor, cronExpression, task);
executor.schedule(cronTask, cronTask.getNextExecutionDelay());
```

Of course you have to deal with all the aspects of serialization and deserialization and potentially you might have to write your own serializers.

One way of avoiding passing the IScheduledExecutorService is implementing HazelcastInstanceAware on your CronTask and then getting the executor from the instance.